# Fetch specific data from YQL JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, cordova, yql

I am currently working on a small project with Ionic Cordova and AngularJS. Within this project I would like to fetch current information from a website using YQL. My $http.jsonp request looks like this:

```
*"https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imensa.de%2Fhildesheim%2Fmensa-uni%2Findex.html'%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22primary%20meal%22%5D'&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK"*
```

which translates into this YQL Console Query:

```
*select * from html where url='http://www.imensa.de/hildesheim/mensa-uni/index.html' and xpath='//div[@class="primary meal"]'*
```

The JSON Data structure that I am now receiving is a bit confusing for me since it doesn't look like straight forward JSON.

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 8,
  "created": "2015-09-03T06:27:03Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "div": [
    {
     "class": "primary meal",
     "id": "m2267999",
     "div": {
      "class": "description",
      "p": "Gebackener Seelachs mit Remoulade"
     },
     "p": {
      "class": "price",
      "span": {
       "title": "Preis für Studierende",
       "content": "2,10 €"
      }
     },
     "ul": {
      "class": "attributes",
      "li": [
       "Fisch",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Zusatz"
       },
       "Farbstoff",
       "Süßungsmittel",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Allergen"
       },
       "Ei",
       "Gluten",
       "Senf",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Zuletzt"
       },
       "23.07.2015"
      ]
     }
    },
    {
     "class": "primary meal",
     "id": "m3472645",
     "div": {
      "class": "description",
      "p": "Kartoffel-Erbseneintopf in Sojarahm mit Koriander und Minze"
     },
     "p": {
      "class": "price",
      "span": {
       "title": "Preis für Studierende",
       "content": "2,00 €"
      }
     },
     "ul": {
      "class": "attributes",
      "li": [
       "Vegan",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Zusatz"
       },
       "Antioxidationsmittel",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Allergen"
       },
       "Gluten",
       "Soja",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Zuletzt"
       },
       "23.07.2015"
      ]
     }
    },
    {
     "class": "primary meal",
     "id": "m1258254",
     "div": {
      "class": "description",
      "p": "Hähnchen Piccata mit Tomatensauce"
     },
     "p": {
      "class": "price",
      "span": {
       "title": "Preis für Studierende",
       "content": "2,10 €"
      }
     },
     "ul": {
      "class": "attributes",
      "li": [
       "Geflügel",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Zusatz"
       },
       "Farbstoff",
       "Geschwefelt",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Allergen"
       },
       "Ei",
       "Gluten",
       "Milch",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Zuletzt"
       },
       "23.07.2015"
      ]
     }
    },
    {
     "class": "primary meal",
     "id": "m6583065",
     "div": {
      "class": "description",
      "p": "Kräuterkartoffeln"
     },
     "p": {
      "class": "price",
      "span": {
       "title": "Preis für Studierende",
       "content": "0,40 €"
      }
     },
     "ul": {
      "class": "attributes",
      "li": [
       "Vegan",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Zuletzt"
       },
       "25.08.2015"
      ]
     }
    },
    {
     "class": "primary meal",
     "id": "m3478290",
     "div": {
      "class": "description",
      "p": "Penne Rigate"
     },
     "p": {
      "class": "price",
      "span": {
       "title": "Preis für Studierende",
       "content": "0,40 €"
      }
     },
     "ul": {
      "class": "attributes",
      "li": [
       "Vegan",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Allergen"
       },
       "Gluten",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Zuletzt"
       },
       "23.07.2015"
      ]
     }
    },
    {
     "class": "primary meal",
     "id": "m4797363",
     "div": {
      "class": "description",
      "p": "Pfannengemüse"
     },
     "p": {
      "class": "price",
      "span": {
       "title": "Preis für Studierende",
       "content": "0,50 €"
      }
     },
     "ul": {
      "class": "attributes",
      "li": [
       "Vegan",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Zuletzt"
       },
       "23.07.2015"
      ]
     }
    },
    {
     "class": "primary meal",
     "id": "m2931855",
     "div": {
      "class": "description",
      "p": "Creme-Dessert Erdbeer"
     },
     "p": {
      "class": "price",
      "span": {
       "title": "Preis für Studierende",
       "content": "0,50 €"
      }
     },
     "ul": {
      "class": "attributes",
      "li": [
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Allergen"
       },
       "Milch",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Zuletzt"
       },
       "23.07.2015"
      ]
     }
    },
    {
     "class": "primary meal",
     "id": "m943602",
     "div": {
      "class": "description",
      "p": "Kirschquark"
     },
     "p": {
      "class": "price",
      "span": {
       "title": "Preis für Studierende",
       "content": "0,50 €"
      }
     },
     "ul": {
      "class": "attributes",
      "li": [
       "Vegetarisch",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Allergen"
       },
       "Milch",
       {
        "class": "group",
        "content": "Zuletzt"
       },
       "gestern"
      ]
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

I already figured out that I can iterate through this object using statements like:

```
{{ data.query.results.div.div.p }}
```

for example to get the "primary meal" p-tag which always contains the meal title. But how about information that is not always the same? For example when I want to get all the allergens of a meal I would have to get all the data after

```
"content": "Allergen"
```

until the next

```
"class": "group",
```

And I have absolutely no idea how to do this.
If you have any advice let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply loop through your data, check for the Allergen tag, and add to an array.  I made a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jeg9dna8/ .  You can extend this strategy to the rest of your data.

```
var list = data.query.results.div[0].ul.li;
var isAllergen = false;
var allergens = [];

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = list[i];
    if(item.class && item.class == 'group')
    {
        if(item.content && item.content == 'Allergen')
        {
            isAllergen = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isAllergen = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(isAllergen)
        {
            allergens.push(item);
        }
    }
}

var result = '';
for(var i = 0; i < allergens.length; i++) {
    result += allergens[i];
    if(i < allergens.length - 1) result += ', ';
}

document.getElementById('allergens').innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D that helped ... I already had everything working to create a master detail view and now thanks to your answers it is possible for me to show the specific allergens. I know stackoverflow told me not to write thanks in the comments but still :D thank you

Answer (score 0):

If paste the returned JSON data inside [a JSON linter](http://jsonlint.com/) you can see that it's valid JSON. Nothing strange.

Keep in mind that `data.query.results.div` is an array so you should use angular dedicated statement to loop (if you are in a angular view) or a classic `for` if you are in a JavaScript file.

Comment: thank you too :D I really doubted that the JSON Data is structured correctly. Dunno but it didn't seem right to me, but I am still new to JavaScript and I always thought that JSON just has one layer basically like { id: '1', name: 'test' } etc...